# Permission denied to run set Identity_insert to table

Tags: replication, permissions, sybase, sybase-ase

I have just setup the ASE-ASE replication with a column as IDENTITY, when I tried to resume my DSI connection of my replication server, I'm hitting the error `Message from server: Message: 10369, State 2, Severity 14 -- 'Permission denied. You must be either the database or the object owner or have sa_role to perform this operation.` Further check from the dump queue, I could see some transaction is trying to do insert to the table with IDENTITY column, and probably it hits permission denied `set identity_insert customer on insert into customer (id, name) values (1,'Ben')set identity_insert customer off`. May I know how can I grant my replication user to be able to run the `set identity_insert` and `set identity_update` command?
Appreciate if you could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`set identity_insert` (and `set identity_update`) requires the user issuing the command to be the db owner, the object owner or have sa permissions.

Most DBAs will alias the maintuser as the database owner (`dbo`) in the replicate database.

While the DSI is down:

```
-- issued in the replicate database
exec sp_dropuser <maintuser>
go
exec sp_addalias <maintuser>,dbo
go
```

Now resume the DSI and the insert should go through.

---

If you're running newer versions of ASE (15.7, 16) you can enable granular permissions and then go through and grant individual permissions to the maintuser (eg, `identity_insert` and `identity_update`).

Comment: I got the result `Warning: the specified account is currently active. Nothing changed` when I run `sp_dropuser <maintuser>`. and when I run `exec sp_addlias <maintuser>, dbo`, it said that my maintuser is already a user in the replicate database. Any advise? My Sybase version is still ASE 15.5.

Comment: Make sure the DSI is suspended (this will log the maintuser out of the RDB) before trying to drop the user.  The `sp_dropuser` has to succeed before you can run `sp_addalias`. If you're using the maintuser for other purposes then you'll need to make sure there are no instances of said user actually in the RDB when you run `sp_dropuser`.